# Textbox date to database

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

I have the following code which worked fine on a .net 1.1 website:

```
objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8))
objSQLCommand.Parameters("@date").Value = txtDate.Text
```

This doesn't work on a .net 3.5 server.

I'm getting a message saying that it can't convert a string to datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
objSQLCommand.Parameters("@date").Value = Convert.ToDate(txtDate.Text)
```

follow-up question, what is the format of the date in your textbox? Maybe you can take advantage of **[`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx#Y0)** or [**`ParseExact`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) also.

```
Dim provider As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
Dim dateString as String = txtDate.Text '08/10/2012
Dim format As String = "d" 
objSQLCommand.Parameters("@date").Value = Date.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider)
```

Comment: Format of the date is day/month/year.  So today would be 08/10/2012.